# automorphism between transcendental elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, transcendental-numbers

**Problem:** Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be transcendental elements over $\mathbb{Q}$, show that there exists automorphism $\sigma$ of $\mathbb{C}$, such that $\sigma(\alpha) = \beta$

**My attempt:** Because $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}$, then they are naturally isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) \cong \mathbb{Q}(x)$, $\mathbb{Q}(\beta) \cong \mathbb{Q}(y)$. Here $\mathbb{Q}(x), \mathbb{Q}(y)$ are quotient field of polynominal rings over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[y]$. Let $\phi: \mathbb{Q}[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}[y]; \text{ satisfies } \phi(x) = y$. Then $\phi$ is obviously an isomorphism, and I can extend $\phi$ to $\psi: \mathbb{Q}(x) \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}(y)$. Therefore, $\mathbb{Q}(x) \cong \mathbb{Q}(y)$ (This is trivial tho) and so, I get $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) \cong \mathbb{Q}(\beta)$. From the way how I defined $\psi$, it satisfies $\psi(\alpha) = \beta$. This is what I needed.

I thought I'm done now, but I also think I'm missing something(because this looks trivial and I did almost nothing).
Is my solution fine?

---

**(edit)** My first attempt was not enough, so I try giving the 2nd one.

**2nd attempt:** Let $\phi$ be defined above. Now I extend $\phi$ to $\tilde{\phi}: \mathbb{C}[\alpha] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}[\beta]$, $\tilde{\phi}(\alpha) = \beta$. And in this case, because $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are in $\mathbb{C}$,$\mathbb{C}[\alpha]$ and $\mathbb{C}[\beta]$ are just $\mathbb{C}$. But I don't know this $\tilde{\phi}$ is an automorphism or not. $\tilde{\phi}$ satisfies $\tilde{\phi}(\alpha) = \beta$ and $\tilde{\phi}(z) = z$ for any $z \in \mathbb{C}-\{\alpha\}$. I think if I can say $\tilde{\phi}(\beta) = \alpha$, then I can say $\tilde{\phi} \in Aut(\mathbb{C})$, but nothing ensures $\tilde{\phi}$ holds that. Maybe I misunderstanding something.

If $\tilde{\phi}$ is an automorphism, then I'm done.

Comment: But you haven't extended the map up to $\bf C$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Oh no you are right, then I have to improve something $\phi$..

Comment: @GerryMyerson I edited my post but it isn't enough still. Can you check it if you don't mind, please? Thank you.

Comment: You can't extend the way you have done. You've got to ensure, for example that $\sqrt{\alpha}$ maps to $\pm\sqrt{\beta}$ and so on. My recollection is that you need some big guns here.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Yes you're completely right. I didn't notice that, this doesn't work at all. I need a whole different approach then.

Comment: I seem to remember a theorem "an isomorphism $\sigma:K\to L$ can be lifted to an isomorphism $\bar{\sigma}:\bar{K}\to \bar{L}$ of the algebraic closures". So lift your $\sigma$ to the algebraic closures; then take transcendence bases and lift to the extensions by these by means of the 1--1 corr of the tr bases, finally lift to algebraic closures of these which ought in each case to be $\mathbb{C}$. Or so I remember it.

Comment: Thank you @ancientmathematician. Actually I knew the theorem but I didn't know how to use it.. it's "vague" theorem for me. I'm gonna review it and think this problem again.